# How to write wordpress plugins faster to load?

Tags: plugins, include

I am writing a wordpress plugin 
The problem is this plugin effecting website performance.
I need tips to make my plugin faster, any help would be amazing.

My plugin contains several classes and I am including all of them in the main php file also using mostly "init" for my actions.

```
$inc_path = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/doctor-profile/';
require_once $inc_path . 'includes/helpers.php';

include_once $inc_path . 'plugin-template.php';
include_once $inc_path . 'includes/installer.php';
include_once $inc_path . 'includes/shortcodes.php';
include_once $inc_path . 'includes/options.php';
include_once $inc_path . 'includes/registration.php';
include_once $inc_path . "includes/login.php";
include_once $inc_path . 'includes/upload.php';
include_once $inc_path . "includes/editprofile.php";

$helper = new SalamatiInstaller();
$editProfile = new SalamatiEditProfile();
$shortCodes = new SalamatiShortCodes();
$options = new SalamatiOptions();
$login = new SalamatiLogin();
$registration = new SalamatiRegistration();

//
```

When the plugin is enabled the website load time is 9 second and when the plugin is deactivated the website load time is 5 second.
this is how I am including my classes.
Any Tips Anything regardless of my code would be amazing thanks.

Comment: you can load the classes on demand with this : http://php.net/autoload

Comment: Showing this code doesn't give any clue as to what could be happening.

Comment: Also, why are you loading them from a file in your root wordpress directory, this somewhat foreshadows how the code is implemented into wordpress as a whole, but again, we would need more context (code) to deduce that.

Comment: I have got a lots of codes. 
There must be some methods faster than the others for example using init action is different than using after_setup_theme performance wise and other stuff. The kind of coding method that experience proves that it is faster than other methods.
sort of general performance coding advice.
thanks